# Is it possible to create a live-USB with more than one Linux distribution?

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb, usb-drive, usb-installation

I'd like to have in a single USB-drive the choice of different Linux distributions, for both live or installation to a computer.

Would it be possible? A kind of grub on live-USB?

In my case I have in mind having Ubuntu, Mint, UbuntuStudio.

Comment: Yes it is possible, you can use multiboot : https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

Comment: I agree with @Mitch  , this question can be deleted because it's  been asked and answered where he says . I'll check in Meta how to deal with this.

Comment: No reason to delete. Everything is fine as it is. The question has been marked as a duplicate so now of someone searches for the same thing, they'll find your question and be redirected to the dupe.

Comment: MultiBootUSB will make a USB drive that can boot over 150 distros, it is based on grub2 iso boot. Ubuntu versions and derivatives can each have a persistence file.